# WebSocket SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

I'm getting a `SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified`, while trying to connect to a WebSocket on Firefox.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
  <body>
    <script>
    var socket = new WebSocket('127.0.0.1:1234');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: If this page does not help solving your problem, try a different browser. Chrome gave me a better error message then firefox for example.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It seems like the scheme is mandatory when trying to connect to a WebSocket, so this:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:1234');
```

works just fine (or as @RaulNoheaGoodness pointed out in the comments, `wss://` when using WebSocket over TLS).

Comment: if protocol is wrong (should be ws: or wss: not http: or https: ), then you get the error